# Exactly what time of the day was the UN charter official?

Tags: political-history

I have been searching for information about the creation of the United Nations.
The [UN website](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/un-charter) says that the official date of creation was October 24, 1945.
The same information can be found in Wikipedia.

However I cannot find information for the exact time of the event.
Do you know at what exact time of the day the UN charter became official?
Can you provide some journal or official document giving that detail?

Answer (score 3):

> **... at what exact time of the day the UN charter became official?**

Article 109 of the [original charter](https://treaties.un.org/doc/publication/ctc/uncharter.pdf), which since subsequent amendments is Article 110 in the [current charter in 2021](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/un-charter/full-text), says

> 3. The present Charter shall come into force
>    upon the deposit of ratifications by the Republic
>    of China, France, the Union of Soviet Socialist
>    Republics, the United Kingdom of Great Britain
>    and Northern Ireland, and the United States of
>    America, and by a majority of the other signatory
>    states.

So you'd have to know the exact times of deposit of ratifications of each of the fifty nations represented at the conference of 26 June 1945 at which the charter was signed.

It may be that these times were not recorded.

The UN only says

> It had therefore been provided that the Charter would come into force when the Governments of China, France, Great Britain, the Soviet Union and the United States and a majority of the other signatory states had ratified it and deposited notification to this effect with the State Department of the United States. On October 24, 1945, this condition was fulfilled and the United Nations came into existence.

I imagine that people didn't turn up in the middle of the night to deposit their ratification - assuming they were in paper form. So you can expect it probably occurred in reasonable working hours.

Comment: [The UN website](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/un-charter/full-text) says it's Article 110, not 106.

Comment: @Spencer: Thanks I was mistaken, it's article 109 in the original charter which I was reading (https://treaties.un.org/doc/publication/ctc/uncharter.pdf ). Subsequent revisions changed numbering. Answer updated.

Comment: The "Time of day" is probably indeterminate, because even if we knew which country's deposit was the critical one, we don't know if a particular manner of deposit, or maybe its announcement, made the deposit "official". Did the President or Secretary of State have to sign off on it, or maybe some lower-level State Department official? Did it sit in someone's inbox, or was there a formal presentation?